# How to wrap selected text in a textarea?

Tags: jquery, textarea

How can I get the user selected text (just inside textarea) and apply actions to it something like wrap the selection `[#bold]selected text[/bold]`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Building off what Soufiane posted, here's the code translated to jquery with the ability to pass in the open and close tags:

```
function wrapText(elementID, openTag, closeTag) {
    var textArea = $('#' + elementID);
    var len = textArea.val().length;
    var start = textArea[0].selectionStart;
    var end = textArea[0].selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
    var replacement = openTag + selectedText + closeTag;
    textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
}
```

Usage would then be like so:

```
wrapText("myTextArea", "[#bold]", "[/bold]");
```

Comment: In case anyone ever wants it, here's a coffeescript version of this function: https://gist.github.com/2938205

Comment: Would be nice if the final selected text included the insertion, not only the initial selection. Or maybe jump the caret to the end of the new string...

Comment: Ok, this does the trick `textArea[0].selectionEnd = end + openTag.length + closeTag.length;` (after the last line).

Comment: To prevent the wrapper from being added at the beginning of the textarea when no text is selected, wrap the last line from @richleland like so:

`if(selectedText != 0) {`
`textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement + textArea.val().substring(end, len));`
`}`

Answer (score 9):

```
function wrapAsLink(url){
  var textarea = document.getElementById("myTa");
  var len = textarea.value.length;
  var start = textarea.selectionStart;
  var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
  var sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);
  var replace = '<a href="'+url+'">' + sel + '</a>';
  textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,start) + replace +
  textarea.value.substring(end,len);
}
```

This function may help you to do what you want with some tweaks. I found it [here](http://osdir.com/ml/jQuery/2009-02/msg03157.html).