# Textarea - how to highlight keystrings with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, syntax-highlighting, codehighlighter

I am looking for a javascript that can help me to change the color of a text inside the textarea tag. For example, to have a variable in the javascript:

```
var a = '<div class="carleft"><p class="coto1">';
```

now, the javascript should make the text that is inside the variable, to be displayed as bold with red color in the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

See this previous question/answer: [jQuery wrap selected text in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712417/jquery-wrap-selected-text-in-a-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

Inner HTML of the textarea element you cannot change the styles/colors of the partial words or characters.

You should use  or some other element to implement this.

You can consider the

contenteditable="true" attribute for this purpose.

By using this attribute you can dynamically edit any html element. Which was styled before.

Answer (score 0):

A textarea does not support different styles or colors in the text. You can use `contenteditable="true"`, but that will probably give the user more freedom than you want. I think a better option would be to use a library like [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) or [MDK-Editor](http://www.mdk-photo.com/editor/).

Comment: There is a way for a textarea, but i don't know how. http://www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/codeedit/

Comment: @xzappa - I looked at that script, and it seems that they also convert a textarea to a contenteditable div.