# Highlight first word in autocomplete input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have an app where the user types a word and an autocomplete appears. When the select the appropriate autocomplete, it's added to the `input` field and the user keeps typing. I would very much like to highlight that word in the *input box* (not in the autocomplete list) and have the rest of the words in the box not appear highlighted, but I can't find any examples of this.

```
$(searchBoxId).autocomplete({
    source:      keys,
    delay:       0,
    selectFirst: true,
    select:      function(event, ui) {
        var TABKEY = 9;
        this.value = ui.item.value;

        if (event.keyCode == TABKEY) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.value = this.value + " ";
            // XXX something goes here?
            this.focus();
        }

        return false;
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    minLength: 2
});
```

This is jquery 1.8.20. By "highlight", I mean "able to make it look visually distinct in a manner similar to how Facebook or Google+ can highlight usernames".

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery wrap selected text in a textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712417/jquery-wrap-selected-text-in-a-textarea)

Comment: or possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field

Comment: Mark, neither is a duplicate, unfortunately. The first embeds the raw HTML in the input field and the second selects text in an input field. Thanks for the pointers, though.

Comment: I do not think you will find any other way than those two options for this.  Another "option" would be to layer a div over the text input and highlight that way with wraps around the text you want highlighted, but that is not what you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, you might want to look at using something like [jQuery Tags](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/).

It supports autocomplete and does the data-differentiation you're looking for.

The basic concept is though that you take your text box and make it a div with the `contenteditable` flag set. Listen for `keypress` events -- specifically the space bar and the enter key.  When they're hit, you grab the most recently entered text (that already isn't "tagged") and create a `<div>` and append it.

Or just use the plugin...