# highlight current line in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea box with multiple lines. I want to change the background color of the current line where the cursor is on, similar to the way [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) highlighting it's current line of code.
How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142527/highlight-text-inside-of-a-textarea

Comment: This also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650534/how-to-select-line-of-text-in-textarea