# textarea specifice text selection onmouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to select a specific word from textArea ?

suppose I have a statement inside textArea (The quick brown fox .) so how can I select the words onmouseOver ? I mean in mouseover I should be able to select any of those words .

Comment: How about doing a little research beforehand? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field) or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650534/how-to-select-line-of-text-in-textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650534/how-to-select-line-of-text-in-textarea) ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select line of text in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650534/how-to-select-line-of-text-in-textarea)